# Need to update products quantity to zero after stripe checkout and webhook hits in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am putting together a site for an artist to sell their art pieces.  It uses stripe checkout for payments.  I've got the checkout and webhook set up and I need to update the product's quantity to 0 once the webhook hits and the checkout session is completed.

Here is the checkout controller(think of piece as product)

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController

  def create
    piece = Piece.find(params[:id])

    if piece.nil?
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end 

    @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: [:card],
      line_items: [{
        name: piece.name,
        description: piece.description,
        amount: (piece.price*100).to_i,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 1
      }],
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
      },
      success_url: checkout_success_url,
      cancel_url: checkout_cancel_url
      )

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

  end 

  def success   

  end

  def cancel

  end


end
```

Here is the webhook events controller

```
class WebhookEventsController < ApplicationController
  # ignore CSRF
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create

    if !valid_signatures?
      render json: { message: "Invalid sigs"}, status: 400
      return
    end

    # idempotent
    if !WebhookEvent.find_by(source: params[:source], external_id: external_id).nil?
      render json: { message: "Already Processed #{ external_id }"}
      return
    end

    event = WebhookEvent.create(webhook_params)
    ProcessEventsJob.perform_later(event.id)    
    render json: params

  end

  def valid_signatures?
    if params[:source] == 'stripe'
      begin
        wh_secret = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :wh)
        Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
          request.body.read,
          request.env["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE" ],
          wh_secret
        )
      rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
        return false
      end
    end
    true
  end

  def external_id
    return params[:id] if params[:source] == 'stripe'

    SecureRandom.hex
  end

  def webhook_params
    {
      source: params[:source],
      data: params.except(:source, :action, :controller).permit!,
      external_id: external_id
    }
  end
end
```

Here is the stripe handler where I believe the code to update the piece quantity should go

```
module Events
  class StripeHandler
    def self.process(event)
      stripe_event = Stripe::Event.construct_from(event.data)

      case stripe_event.type
      when 'checkout.session.completed'
        checkout_session = stripe_event.data.object
        # now can do #{ checkout_session.customer }.. or some attribute of checkout_session object
        puts "*** Do things here i.e. logic for emails/inventory management"

      end
    end
  end
end
```

All this so I can basically disable the purchase button on the art piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple notes here:

1. You might want to set `client_reference_id` to the Piece's ID, which makes reconciling this easier: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-client_reference_id
2. You need to either inspect the `line_items` on the completed session or use `client_reference_id` to find the item your customer purchased after the session is completed.

Your controller logic looks correct so far. You'll need a `quantity` field on Piece. I'm assuming you pass `{client_reference_id: piece.id}` in your CheckoutSession creation. With that assumption, your webhook handling logic looks like this:

```rb
module Events
  class StripeHandler
    def self.process(event)
      stripe_event = Stripe::Event.construct_from(event.data)

      case stripe_event.type

      when 'checkout.session.completed'
        Piece.transaction do
          piece = Piece.find(id: checkout.client_reference_id)
          raise Exception.new("item already purchased!") if piece.quantity == 0
          piece.quantity = 0
          piece.save!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This implements a simple "first person to pay wins" scenario, so the first person who goes through Checkout for a given Piece, pays, and whose `checkout.session.completed` webhook gets sent to your application & processed first will get the Piece. If two people pay at the same time, only one can get the Piece, so you may want to do something like refund the customer automatically & send them an email.

I used a [database transaction](https://medium.com/@kristenrogers.kr75/rails-transactions-the-complete-guide-7b5c00c604fc) to update the Piece so that if two customers somehow pay at the exact same time, we will not accidentally give *both* customers the Piece.

Comment: Thank you this set me on the right path.  I added `client_reference_id: piece.id` to the checkout session creation and added the Piece.transaction code you wrote in the stripe handler.  I just had to change `piece = Piece.find(id: checkout.client_reference_id)` to `piece = Piece.find_by(id: checkout_session.client_reference_id)` and it works!